# python local databse mssql connection string

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, localdb

I'm attempting to connect my SQL Server database to python using this documentation as a guide. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7293/pyodbc-open-source-access-odbc-databases/.

I am running into an issue with the driver where I keep getting this error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Diane\Documents\ProjectDB.py", line 3, in <module>    
>     conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER= {ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}; \  
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18
> for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to
> SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string
> attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A
> network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to MSSQLLocalDB. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. (53)')
```

I am currently using this script:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER= {ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}; \
                        SERVER=MSSQLLocalDB; \
                        DATABASE=Christopher_Kirkwood_DB; \
                        Trust_Connection=yes')
```

I have also have downloaded the driver provided here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-windows?view=sql-server-ver15

I have tried opening odbc and checked the configuration settings like the error suggests but haven't found anything that fixes my issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is the whole issue, but I think the keyword is `Trusted_Connection` not `Trust_Connection`

Comment: Also, remove the space after `DRIVER=`

Comment: @Xedni I changed these and still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have TCP/IP connections open on the database server? I'm not sure if pyodbc uses that or not, but you might try enabling that and seeing if it helps.

Comment: If you have the [SQL Server Express LocalDB feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb) installed then have you tried using `SERVER=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;`? Note the doubled backslash, since backslash is Python's escape character.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This seems to have worked.